# Web Page Div Overlay For All Contents

Tags: css, layout, html, overlay, opacity

I have a webpage that is styled using CSS

The contents of the web page are contained within DIVs.

```
Example:
<div id="container">
<div id="ticker">
</div>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

I want a background on the container div that will show as a semi transparent background (in a desired color), and then all the contents inside the div to appear normally without transparency.

I have tried methods including apply a opacity to the parent div, but it applies it to all the child divs which I do not want.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 1x1 background image (a png) at whatever transparency of whatever color you'd like and let it repeat.

Comment: I don't want the background image of the webpage to be transparent. Only the container div that holds all the content of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an rgba value for your background color instead and set the alpha value to your desired opacity level:

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.125);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: I don't want the background image of the webpage to be transparent. Only the container div that holds all the content of the webpage

Comment: In that case I would recommend placing an image on your page representing the background image you want and set it's z-index lower than any of its siblings.

Comment: Or another option would be to have another div with its background image set as your background image and then embed the image inside your css file on that div's background-image property.

Comment: Why would you need to? The container div would be semi transparent using my first answer, this second div would have your background image set on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rgba`  value for this. Write like this:

```
#container{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

For IE there filter for this like this:

```
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000)";  
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;
```

You can  generator your rgba filter from here http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: What if I have an image as the background in the BODY style tag?

Comment: You can give image also but an image send an extra HTTP request when your web page is load. So, it's good to give with css.